# How can I get ROLLUP Sum in MDX Query?

Tags: sql-server, ssas, mdx, adventureworks

I use `SSAS` and `Adventure Works DW 2008`.

What is the `MDX` to get this?:

Measure: `Reseller Sales Amount`
Day : 2014/03/05
and
Month = 2014/03 ( Sum(Day 01-05) )
and
Year 2014 (Sum(Mount 01 and 02) + Sum(Day 01-05))

```
With 
set Serial_Month as
    [Date].[Calendar].Currentmember.parent.FIRSTSIBLING
                    :
    [Date].[Calendar].Currentmember.parent
set Serial_Day as 
    [Date].[Calendar].Currentmember.FIRSTSIBLING
                    :
    [Date].[Calendar].Currentmember
Select
non empty 
{
    [Date].[Calendar].[Date],
    Serial_Day,
    Serial_Month
} on  columns ,
non empty {[Measures].[Reseller Sales Amount]} on rows
From [Adventure Works]
```

Comment: not too sure how this script relates to your requirement. Do you just want the reseller sales amount for a very specific date?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following specifies some specific dates and then creates a `calculated member`.

I'm not 100% sure what you require but is the following heading in the right direction?

note: I don't have the same date ranges in my Adventure works as you.

```
WITH 
SET [SpecificDate] AS
    [Date].[Calendar].[Date].&[20080401]
SET [SpecificMonths] AS
    {   [Date].[Calendar].[Month].&[2008]&[3]: 
        [Date].[Calendar].[Month].&[2008]&[7] }
MEMBER [Date].[Calendar].[AggregatedMonths]     AS 
    (
        AGGREGATE([SpecificMonths])
    )
SET [SpecificYear] AS
    [Date].[Calendar].[Calendar Year].&[2008]
MEMBER [Date].[Calendar].[CalcMember]   AS 
    (
        [Date].[Calendar].[Date].&[20080401] + 
        [Date].[Calendar].[Month].&[2008]&[3] + 
        [Date].[Calendar].[Calendar Year].&[2008]
    )
Select
{
    [Measures].[Reseller Sales Amount]
} ON COLUMNS, 
{
    [SpecificDate],
    [SpecificMonths],
    [Date].[Calendar].[AggregatedMonths],
    [SpecificYear],
    [Date].[Calendar].[CalcMember]
} ON ROWS
FROM [Adventure Works]
```

If you'd like all dates (with data) on rows and then various measures on the columns, such as `mtd` and `ytd` then you can do something like the following:

```
With 
MEMBER [Measures].[CurrentDay] AS
    AGGREGATE( 
        [Date].[Calendar].Currentmember,
        [Measures].[Reseller Sales Amount]
    )
MEMBER [Measures].[CurrentMonth] AS
  AGGREGATE( 
        [Date].[Calendar].Currentmember.parent,
        [Measures].[Reseller Sales Amount]
    )
MEMBER [Measures].[CurrentMTD] AS
    AGGREGATE(
            MTD([Date].[Calendar].CURRENTMEMBER),
            [Measures].[Reseller Sales Amount]
    )
MEMBER [Measures].[CurrentYTD] AS
    AGGREGATE(
            YTD([Date].[Calendar].CURRENTMEMBER),
            [Measures].[Reseller Sales Amount]
    )
Select
    non empty 
    {
        [Measures].[CurrentDay],
        [Measures].[CurrentMonth],
        [Measures].[CurrentMTD],
        [Measures].[CurrentYTD]
    } 
    on  columns,
    non empty 
    {
        [Date].[Calendar].[Date]
    }
    having [Measures].[CurrentDay]<>null 
    on rows
From [Adventure Works]
```

Comment: merci.but in SET [SpecificMonth] AS
    [Date].[Calendar].[Month].&[2008]&[3] I need sum of [Month].&[2008]&[1] until [Month].&[2008]&[3]

Comment: you can use the `:` operator between the start and end of the date range as you did in OP

Comment: I do not want to specify a specific time. 
I want it for all rows. 
I want every date in every row, the sum of every single day, the totals for all months of the year beginning with the day of the month, and the total number of days. 
For example, imagine a row following the date 
04/02/2010: 


Sales on 02/04/2010 
Sales totals months = 02/04/2010 + 01/04/2010 
Year = total sales: 2010/01 + 2010/02 + 2010/03 +2010/04/02 + 2010/04/01

Comment: ok - sounds a bit more like custom measures - I'll add some code later